# json data not responding to alert

Tags: jquery, json, url, twitter

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form#search').bind("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').html('');
        var query1 = urlencode($('input[name="user_a"]').val()); //userA

        $.getJSON('http://twitterank.com/api/get?id=' + query1 + '&devkey=8909d7273e0ab578bde409571747fc9e&callback=?',
            function (data1) {
                alert('JSON data string is: ' + data1.status);
            });
    });
});
```

this is a code that takes JSON feed from [twitterrank.com](http://twitterrank.com) and displays it on the HTML page.

now the API of twitterank says that the URL http://twitterank.com/api/get?id=Anand_Dasgupta&devkey=8909d7273e0ab578bde409571747fc9e (click to see) will give back the json data...the devkey has been provided by twitterank itself...

but in the code, the alert message doesn't respond when I run

Comment: do this in Firefox with firebug, see what's really being sent and coming back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `alert()` never fires, that tells you that the query from twitterank.com is never coming back.  I would `alert()` the query and then try running it from a browser or telnet session to see what's happening.